# Create SSL Client Certificate on different Web Server

Tags: apache, openssl, self-signed, dmz

I have a web server (Apache) and configured a CA on this machine to create self-signed ssl client certificates (via openssl). Because the web server is in the DMZ, my question is: Is there any way to create the ssl client certs on a different machine (in the internal network) and can the web server in the DMZ be configured to use these certs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can (but you will of course need the CA key). It doesn't matter on which host you create a certificate.

E.g. when you purchase a certificate from a trusted CA they create it on another machine, possibly on another continent :)